# Visual Basic 6 reference missing for IDocHostUIHandler

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I'm working on migrating code from Visual Basic 6 to Visual Basic.NET, but before I can do that I need to get it to build. Currently I cannot get it to build because of a missing reference in an MSHTML for an IDocHostUIHandler. Specfically I get the error on the line using DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DIALOG. I've tried added different references, but the error stays the same. If it makes any difference, I'm running XP with IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN says that the `IDocHostUIHandler` interface is defined in `mshtmhst.idl` which is in the Platform SDK. I can't find this defined in any DLL or type library so you may need to compile the IDL into your own library to register.

You will also need to make sure that there are no references listed as "(MISSING)" as these cause random object reference problems.

Comment: +1. But first make sure you've really looked everywhere for the custom type library (tlb) created by those who wrote this code in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a module

```
Public Enum DOCHOSTUIFLAG
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DIALOG = 1
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_HELP_MENU = 2
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER = 4
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_SCROLL_NO = 8
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_SCRIPT_INACTIVE = &H10
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_OPENNEWUI = &H20
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_OFFSCREEN = &H40
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_FLAT_SCROLLBAR = &H80
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DIV_BLOCKDEFAULT = &H100
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ACTIVATE_CLIENTHIT_ONLY = &H200
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_OVERRIDEBEHAVIORFACTORY = &H400
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_CODEPAGELINKEDFONTS = &H800
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_URL_ENCODING_DISABLE_UTF8 = &H1000
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_URL_ENCODING_ENABLE_UTF8 = &H2000
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_FORMS_AUTOCOMPLETE = &H4000
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_INPLACE_NAVIGATION = &H10000
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_IME_ENABLE_RECONVERSION = &H20000
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_BROWSER = &H12
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DESKTOP = &H2E
End Enum
```

Comment: It's more than just a single enumeration, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: There is no standard typelib that contains `IDocHostUIHandler`. The `mshtmhst.idl` declaration will be practicly unusable from VB6. You probably had a custom built typelib with the interface VB-fied so it can be used in VB6. I can give you such version of the interface but it will probably be different than the version your source is compiled with. You have to find the `tlb` file from the original source/coder.